# How to view contents of fmatch() 's hash table?

Tags: r, hashtable

The function `fastmatch::fmatch` creates an attribute for the table passed as an argument; this attribute contains a hash table for subsequent use.  I got as far as:

```
fmatch(dbar,dfoo,nomatch=0) # just to grind dfoo through the function

Rgames> class(attributes(dfoo)$.match.hash)
[1] "match.hash"
Rgames> object.size(attributes(dfoo)$.match.hash)
280 bytes
Rgames> print(attributes(dfoo)$.match.hash)
<hash table>
<hash table>
```

But can't figure out how to display the table contents.  Any ideas?

Comment: Wild guess: the hash table is likely an environment, so try using `ls`.

Comment: `typeof(attributes(dfoo)$.match.hash)` gives `[1] "externalptr"`. Thus, this structure is created and handled separately from R. You can't display it within R.

Comment: @redmode thanks - I was afraid of that :-) .  Go ahead and post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof(attributes(dfoo)$.match.hash)` gives `[1] "externalptr"`.

Thus, this structure is created and handled separately from `R` and you can't display it within `R`.

However, if you *really* want to look into `$.match.hash` - it's possible. Source of `fastmatch` package provides declaration of this structure:

```
typedef struct hash {
  int m, k, els, type;
  void *src;
  SEXP prot, parent;
  struct hash *next;
  hash_index_t ix[1];
} hash_t;
```